# A child moved in Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have tree on Firebase like that:

```
key = 0, 
  value = {
      id=a, 
      content="something", 
      parent_id=...
      level=...
         ...
  }

key = 1, 
      value = {
          id=b, 
          content="something", 
          parent_id=...
          level=...
             ...
      }

key = 2, 
      value = {
          id=c, 
          content="something", 
          parent_id=...
          level=...
             ...
      }

key = 3, 
      value = {
          id=d, 
          content="something", 
          parent_id=...
          level=...
             ...
      }

...............
```

And my listener:

```
private void getData(Query ref){
    ref.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onChildAdded");
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onChildChanged");
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onChildRemoved");
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onChildMoved");
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onCancelled");
        }
    });
}
```

When I move a node, example I move **node 2**(key) to **node 3**, i only get result response in **onChildChanged()** method. Why didn't I get that in **onChildMoved()**?

If I only get result response in **onChildChanged()** when i move a node, the performance of algorithm sort tree is complex and not good because my data so large. If that, how can I determine exactly a node is moved based on result respone in **onChildChanged()**?

Please give me any advise or idea.

P/S: I feeling the Firebase is not good realtime for sync data when node up to about 10.000. Sorry, my english is not good.

Comment: Can you show the code that does "move node 2(key) to node 3"? Because I'm pretty sure that'll allow me to explain the behavior you're seeing.

Comment: @Frank van Puffelen: I just handle data sync from Firebase to my app. So, i'm not implement code because above problem

Comment: You have a situation where `onChildChanged()` executes, but you also expect `onChildMoved()` to be triggered. Without seeing the code for how that situation occurs, it will be difficult to help you.

Comment: Gotta have the code!

Comment: Oops! I'm sorry for late reply. The code implemented on another platform is not change property node when it moved. So, the result response to my app only changed